# Set isActive in view model then checkbox is checked

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js, typescript

I need set true or false for each isActive values in view model then checkbox is checked or not checked in client table. I can't implement data-bind with change isActive values

TypeScript ViewModel:

```
class ModelViewModel{
 products:KnockoutObservableArray<Product>;

  constructor() {
   products = ko.observableArray<Product[]>();
 }
}
```

TypeScript Model:

```
class Product{
 name: KnockoutObservable<string>;
 isActive: KnockoutObservable<boolean>;
}

constructor() {
 this.name = ko.observable<string>();
 this.isActive = ko.observable<boolean>();
}
```

HTML:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: vm.products">
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="chekBx" data-bind="value: isActive"></td>
            <td><span data-bind="text: name"></span></td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What is not working? What is your question?

Comment: @nemesv, I need change check box state in array of objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to use a different binding, `checked` instead of `value`.

[The "checked" binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html).